# Syntax error with nested replace statements

Tags: php

I am getting a syntax error with the follow code snippet:

```
    $handle = $table.'_'.$field;
    if($queryType=='replace') {
        $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'UPDATE '.$table.' SET '.$field.' = replace(replace(replace('.$field.',\''0', ''), '1', ''), '2', '')';
    } else {
        $sql[$handle]['sql'] = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE '.$field.' REGEXP(\''.$search.'\')';
    }
```

I am sure I have just forgot something small but I cant seem to find out what is causing the error.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: why don't you look at the the string you're generating (e.g. `echo $sql[$handle]['sql']` and figure out where the syntax error is on that, then backtrack to figure out where in your code the error is occuring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your syntax error comes from line 3 of the snippet you provided: the end of that line, `',\''0', ''), '1', ''), '2', '')';`, is causing the problem because the single quotes that are supposed to be a part of your SQL statement aren't escaped. Rather than escaping all of them, it's much simpler to just use double quotes to contain that part instead, like this: `",''0', ''), '1', ''), '2', '')";`

Also, your current code is highly susceptible to SQL injection.

Comment: @user1658413 That's a matter of where you placed your double quotes. Use `$field.",'0','')`... instead of `$field.',",''0', '')`... If you want to keep your single quotes you'll have to escape every last single quote that should be part of the SQL statement.

Comment: @user1658413 Probably as many as you'd like, although if you decide to use something like 20 nested statements in SQL, you should most definitely reconsider what you're trying to do.